# When 2nd child form is called in the parent form. 1st child form must close automatically.how can i do that?

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have made a parent form  which can call and display two child forms in it.

But how 1st child form can be closed automatically when second child form is called?

Comment: What do you mean by 'called'? Please show us some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a form in windows forms as MDI Parent form then it will have a property called `MdiChildren` that contains the collections of opened child forms. before opening the second form, you can write the following code to close the first form.

```
this.MdiChildren[0].Close();
```

if multiple child forms are available then you need to access `this.MdiChildren` using a `foreach` loop and search for Form1 and close it.

Comment: Thanks.that solved the problem